# Jquery Date.parse returning NaN in Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a senario where i have to parse two dates for example start date and end date.

```
var startdate = '02/01/2011';
var enddate = '31/12/2011';
```

But if we alert start date

```
 alert(Date.Parse(startdate)); i will get 1296498600000
```

but if i alert enddate

```
 alert(Date.Parse(enddate)); i will get NaN
```

But this is working in other browsers except Chrome, But in other browsers

```
alert(Date.Parse(enddate)); i will get 1370889000000
```

Can anybody know a workaround for this?

Comment: Unable to reproduce, works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/b77DE/1/

Comment: Oh, and by the way the [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method expects the string to be formatted as RFC822 or ISO 8601 date.

Comment: Before Darin deleted the tags, I noticed you were using ASP.NET. Does this export the data to the page? Can we see the .NET code that exports this?

Comment: It's culture related. I get NaN when I alert `enddate`

Comment: Hi guys i have edited my question. please try this. it will not work.

Comment: Dare I say, try swapping it to US format?

Comment: `Date.parse` (lowercase!). And Date format must be `'mm/dd/yyyy'` for `Date.parse`!

Comment: @kara:- As you said that this is culture specific issue then how come this works in other browsers except chrome?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to parse a date without local differences, use the following, instead of `Date.parse()`:

```
var enddate = '31/12/2011'; //DD/MM/YYYY
var split = enddate.split('/');
// Month is zero-indexed so subtract one from the month inside the constructor
var date = new Date(split[2], split[1] - 1, split[0]); //Y M D 
var timestamp = date.getTime();
```

See also: [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: This helps me a lot in resolving, Thanks Rob

Comment: Careful using this - it's just caught me out as months appear to be 0 indexed for some strange reason...    var date = new Date(split[2], parseInt(split[1] - 1), split[0]); worked though.

Comment: It certainly appeared to be dd/mm/yyyy - using this with 28/06/2012 then showing the date in an alert gave me 28th Jul 2012 :S

Comment: @TomAllen Oops, I misunderstand your first comment. I thought that you meant that month was at index zero of the `split` array. The month starts counting at index zero indeed, see [MDN: `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/#Parameters).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

> dateString
>       A string representing an RFC822 or ISO 8601 date.

I've tried your code and I also get `NaN` for the end date, but if i swap the date and month around, it works fine.