# Date.parse() results in NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

```
Date.parse();
```

My [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aBYL/) works fine, but run it in my ide (both Aptana and WebStorm) shows `NaN` in the `console.log()` output.

Really confused about this... Has someone had such experience before?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964922/jquery-date-parse-returning-nan-in-chrome-browser `:)`

Comment: It shows NaN in given JsFiddle link.

Comment: Me running this jsFiddle in Chrome works just fine..and IDE for Chrome and Firefox both no luck....

Comment: Because some browsers accept dates in particular format only. Some formats may run in one but not in other.

Comment: I think that's the beauty of JavaScript, I just start to get used to it...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7KfuM/

Change `-` to `/`

Good read: [Jquery Date.parse returning NaN in Chrome browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964922/jquery-date-parse-returning-nan-in-chrome-browser) **or** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Try this:

```
var firstDayTimestamp = Date.parse("2009/07/13 00:00:00" + "-0500") / 1000;
```

Hope this fits the cause! `B-)`

Comment: Yes. `/` is more consistent than `-`. +1

Comment: `-` is also recognized by IE11 and Edge. I encountered this issue and decided to not to use Date.parse at all. Just as MDN recommends.

Comment: Hiya `:)` @DanilaShutov Interesting, do you know any official docs reference?

Comment: @Tats_innit, see note for 'dateString' parameter.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 3):

The date should be in the IETF date syntax (RFC2822 Section 3.3) format, e.g. "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT", or "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT+0430".

Read more: [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Surprisingly this should be done also for the current (2017) versions of IE (11.x) and FF (56.x) for the Date.parse to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Date.parse will not work for format dd/mm/yyyy
so when format is dd/mm/yyyy 0r dd-mm-yyyy just reverse it

var char = date.charAt(2);//return '/' or '-'

Date.parse(date.split(char).reverse().join(char));

it wil change format to yyyy/mm/dd and parse it