# Firefox refuses to parse date even when properly formatted

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, cross-browser

I have seen that Firefox only successfully parses date objects when fed a string using slashes to delimit month/day/year. [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516332/date-parse-results-in-nan). However, doing this:

```
var given_input = "2014-09-26 08:00:28.787618";
var d = given_input.replace(/-/g, "/");

var myDate = new Date(d); //Date {Invalid Date}
```

It works in Chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*Firefox only successfully parses date objects when fed a string using slashes to delimit month/day/year*" -- this is not entirely true; in fact, [the only *required* date format in ECMAScript 5 is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), which uses dashes. However, it seems that the use of dashes might require a `T` date/time separator, instead of a space.

Comment: Please notice that `1.` your referenced question is over 2 years old and _FireFox_ releases a new version every 6 weeks, i.e. we are now are over 17 versions later. `2.` That question is about `Date.parse` and not `new Date`

Comment: @PaulS. Yes, I see that now. In any case, the problems is the seconds. Apparently only two decimals are allowed. Thanks.

Comment: @thomas actually, it's a valid date if you put a `"T"` instead of a `" "` between the date and time, without having to do anything to the hyphens

Comment: Can you show an example @PaulS? I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @thomas `2014-09-26T08:00:28.787618` -- *it's a valid date if you put a `"T"` instead of a `" "`*

Comment: @thomas this way of writing a date and time is defined by _ISO 8601_ and calendar dates, (optionally combined with) times and timezone offsets in this format should be understood by any modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as it turns out is having more than two decimal places at the end of the seconds. It does not follow the format specified by @apsillers. This works if you don't care about time, only date:

```
input_date.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}).*$/g, "$1/$2/$3");
```